# Argocd The reason for using high memory

Tags: kubernetes, cicd, argocd

I installed 'argo' using helm

I don't know why but... It is confirmed that the memory used by argocd-server is too high.

argocd's replica is a total of one.

May I know what to check first to find out why?

Thanks you

```
10:11:56 root@ubuntu → kubectl get all -n argocd
NAME                                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/argocd-application-controller-0       1/1     Running   1          124d
pod/argocd-dex-server-7946bfbf79-nknkx    1/1     Running   1          124d
pod/argocd-redis-7547547c4f-tv5db         1/1     Running   1          124d
pod/argocd-repo-server-7fb6c84b5b-ph5zl   1/1     Running   1          124d
pod/argocd-server-658fcf5695-hcjjx        1/1     Running   4          124d


10:15:42 root@ubuntu → kubectl top pod argocd-server-658fcf5695-hcjjx -n argocd --use-protocol-buffers
NAME                             CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
argocd-server-658fcf5695-hcjjx   5193m        24365Mi
```

resource : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAcRA.png)

argocd state : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfMad.png)

Comment: Scrap  argocd metrics and check any un-usual activities? Paste an image of the argocd dashboard will be helpful.

Comment: @gohm'c oh Thanks you

Attached is the application dashboard being serviced by Argo.

Thank you for your help, and if there is anything I need to check, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: The metrics dashboard looks like [this](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/metrics/#dashboards). You have quite a number of projects listed, this dashboard may tell you what's on-going when the memory goes crazy. Also take a look at [this](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/4298).